# Why does Google Maps Geocoder not call initialize?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the Google Maps Geocoder to return a LatLng from an address and then initialize the map with that LatLng on center.

I’ve seen a few questions on this topic with suggestions that the map should be initialized first with an arbitrary center then recentered, but that seems wasteful.

The code below works fine until I change the global lat and lon to zero.  The geocder is then called with the address and a LatLng is returned fine.  All I then get is a blank window and the alert in the initialize function is never triggered.

Can someone explain why this isn’t working before I go the route of initializing on 0,0 and then centering?

Thanks

```
var lat = 37.425593;
var lon = -122.075915;
var address = '1600 Amphitheatre Pky, Mountain View, CA';
var LatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

function initialize() {

    alert("2. "+LatLon);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: LatLon,
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLon,
        map: map
    });

}

if (lat == 0 && lon == 0) {
    alert('address = '+address);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                LatLon = results[0].geometry.location;
                alert("1. "+LatLon);
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            } else {
                alert("No results found");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed: " + status);
        }
    });
} else {
    alert('lat/lon = '+lat+' '+lon);
    LatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    alert("1. "+LatLon);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing the latitude and longitude to my map script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936231/passing-the-latitude-and-longitude-to-my-map-script)

Answer (score 0):

The geocoder is asynchronous.  You haven't placed your code in context, but the time it takes to return the coordinates must mean that the window load event has already fired, when the coordinates come back from the server, so the initialize function never runs.  It will work if you use the onload event to start the geocode operation, or if you call initialize directly and put the code at the bottom of the page so it doesn't execute until the page has completely rendered (and the map has a size).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var address = '1600 Amphitheatre Pky, Mountain View, CA';
var LatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

function initialize(LatLon) {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: LatLon,
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLon,
        map: map
    });

}

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
               var LatLon = results[0].geometry.location;
               initialize(LatLon);
            } else {
                alert("No results found");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed: " + status);
        }
    });
</script> 
</body>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_geocodeInitial.html)